# Rails New Model Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple example on a new form to send the notice of success when creating a new item using ajax.
I'm reciving a response from the server with 500 internal error.

new.js.erb

```
$("#flash-messages").html("<%= notice %>")
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Ajax</h1>

<%= form_for(@ajax, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div id="flash-messages" >
</div>
<% if @ajax.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@ajax.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ajax from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @ajax.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
  def create
  @ajax = Ajax.new(ajax_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @ajax.save
    format.html { redirect_to @ajax, notice: 'Ajax was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ajax }
    format.js { redirect_to new_ajax_path, flash[:notice] = "Fudeu" }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @ajax.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Copy your logs that what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 64ms (ActiveRecord: 61.7ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):
  app/controllers/ajaxes_controller.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/ajaxes_controller.rb:29:in `create'

Answer (score 0):

I have found why was bugging my code.
Just nee do remove the flash[:notice] to notice:
Now I`m looking into giving a lifetime to this flash, like 10s and it vanishs
When I have it working I post it here for other people that may strugle as me